# How to call function in my controller in browser url which shows 'hello world' in magento 2.3.5

Tags: magento2, url, controllers

I am here trying to make a hello world message when trying to access my controller function using browser url

```
demomagento.com/app/code/Icosmoz/Unicenta/Controller/Adminhtml/Home/index.php
```

---

This is the path to my controller file.

***In that file i have a function execute(). I have to access that function in my browser***

like

```
http://demomagento.com/app/code/Icosmoz/Unicenta/Controller/Adminhtml/Home/index.php/execute
```

or any other formate of url.

please help me out... Thanks in advance

Comment: You cannot access method with directory path.

Comment: i want to send values to this function from a pos application. So how can i pass that values to a controller in magento 2.3.5

Comment: First of all you need to see routes.xml file of the plugin to see the exact url to access through URL. I cannot tell without looking at the code. Next is you should never pass data from another application directly to the controller, rather you should you use API to do so.

Comment: Can u suggest me how can I pass values from other applications to my Magento controller ?

Comment: Please join the room https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109943/discussion-between-abdul-deepak-dev